# Прописная или строчная буква в названии учреждения: Дума или дума?

Tags: прописная-строчная

ПАС под редакцией Лопатина: [Названия органов власти, учреждений, организаций, обществ, партий | orthographia.ru](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3531) **Государственная дума, Московская городская дума.**

Слово "дума" имеет реальное (не условное) значение, которое указано в словаре. Если писать с прописной буквы, то только как слово *особой важности*. Но в правилах говорится о записи со строчной буквы.

Так почему пишут «*Дума*», например: *Московская городская Дума, Городская Дума Нижнего Новгорода*? Почему пишут: *новости городской Думы?*

Что-нибудь изменилось в правилах? Или правила не читают эрудированные чиновники?

Из словаря:

> ДУМА, 3. Представительное выборное учреждение.   **Городская д.**
>   (выборный орган городского самоуправления).

Comment: А ещё пишут: Генеральный Директор и даже Заместитель Генерального Директора. И так далее... Мало ли что пишут... зато как звучит, с прописной-то!

Comment: [НЕСТАНДАРТНОЕ УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЕ ПРОПИСНОЙ БУКВЫ
В НОВОЙ РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=1.22)

Comment: Но в написании некоторых новых названий наблюдаются колебания, например: Федеральное собрание (Федеральное Собрание), Государственная дума (Государственная Дума), Конституционный суд (Конституционный Суд).  Справочник по литературной правке. Розенталь, Д. Э. В справочнике же по русскому языку: Орфография.Пунктуация ,Розенталь, Д.Э.  уже о колебании ничего не говорится, там однозначно: Государственная Дума.

Comment: Мне кажется, должен соблюдаться порядок, всем понятный, то есть выбор прописной или строчной буквы должен объясняться. Наверное,  логично писать "Государственная Дума", так как это высший орган власти. Но совсем не логично ( и некрасиво как-то) писать "Московская государственная Дума.  Это не высший орган власти,  а само слово "дума" является нарицательным, так же как собрание, парламент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ПАС под редакцией Лопатина:
>   http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3531 **Государственная дума**,
>   **Московская городская дума**.
>
> Так почему пишут "Дума", например: Московская городская Дума...

Э-эх… Если б правописание регулировалось одним-единственным справочником…

К сожалению, это не так. Помимо **ПАС** ведь существуют и **Правила—56**, и справочники **Розенталя**… И если б только они!

Существует и  [**"Справочник по оформлению нормативных правовых актов в Администрации Президента Российской Федерации"**](http://www.garant.ru/products/ipo/prime/doc/70517766/#ixzz4loA5F93q), и [**"Справочник по оформлению  актов в Совете Федерации Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации"**](http://kavdjaradze.ru/spravochnik-po-oformleniyu-aktov-v-sovete-federaci/).
Вот в этих двух последних справочниках и зафиксированы написания, используемые в т. наз. официальных текстах (а на практике – и в современной письменной речи вообще).

Ср.:

в **ПАС:**

*Федеральное **собрание**, Государственная **дума**, Московская городская **дума**, Законодательное **собрание** Ростовской области…*

в **"Справочнике по оформлению нормативных правовых актов в Администрации Президента Российской Федерации"**:

*Федеральное **Собрание**, Государственная **Дума**,  Московская городская **Дума**,  Законодательное **Собрание** Ростовской области…*

===================================

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

По поводу *Государственной Думы/думы*…

**Людмила** в своём ответе в этой теме пишет:

> Есть же общее употребление и официальное, но это касается только
>   написания названий высших органов власти: **Государственная Дума**
>   пишется в официальных государственных документах, например, в
>   Конституции, а в газетах - **Государственная дума**, по правилам.

*По правилам…* По каким?

По-моему, в газетах "думу" пишут по-разному: и с прописной, и со строчной. И оба варианта соответствуют правилам —  только разным. Всё зависит от того, каким правилом и каким справочником пользоваться.

См. правила, приведённые в наиболее авторитетных справочниках.

[**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=88#pp88):

> **§ 189**. В официальных составных названиях органов власти… с прописной буквы пишется **первое слово** и входящие в состав названия
>   имена собственные…
>
> ***Государственная дума***…

**Розенталь** "Классический справочник по русскому языку", М., 2017:

> **§ 16**… В названиях высших органов власти… **все слова**, кроме служебных, пишутся с прописной буквы…
>
> ***Государственная Дума***…
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо бы послать запрос составителям справочника, пусть где-нибудь редакцию поменяют, что же у нас никакого порядка.

Answer (score 3):

```
Так почему пишут "Дума", например: Московская городская Дума,...
```

Смотря кто пишет. Если чиновники,то они пытаются следовать "высокому стилю " юристов.

Есть же общее употребление и официальное, но это касается только написания названий высших органов власти: Государственная Дума пишется в официальных государственных документах,например, в Конституции, а в газетах - Государственная дума, по правилам. Так же как Президент Российской Федерации в официальных документах, указах и президент Российской Федерации в общем употреблении.

А чиновники  считают, что всё ими написанное - это официальная речь, что неверно. Кстати, на официальном сайте Государственной думы оба слова с большой буквы. Видимо, они считают сайт тоже официальным употреблением. А как здесь поспоришь? Не документ, но ведь называется-то "официальный".

Я даже не знаю, как к этому относиться. Может, не стоит разделять общее употребление с официальным? Пусть бы уж всё писалось с большой буквы, как в Конституции, чтоб не путались. Но это решать академикам, нас не спрашивают. Хоть слово дума и внушает уважение, но писать его  правильно со строчной буквы.

Comment: Да, грустно, если даже с выбором буквы  для названия высшего органа власти не могут однозначно определиться и согласовать с существующими правилами, то что ждать от  названий на местах, там у них новости городской Думы.